# How to avoid "_class" field in documents using spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring-data-elasticsearch for my application. I found spring automatically creates dynamic field "_class" in all my documents. I configured my index as a strict dynmaic mapping. I expecting some properties to exclude this field from my document/mapping dynamically.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Disable `writeTypeHint` in the mapping pojo.

```
@Document(indexName = "index", writeTypeHint = WriteTypeHint.FALSE)
public class Test{}
```

Spring document reference

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.3.0-M1/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model.rules

Answer (score 2):

Currently this can not be deactivated. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/1454) to add this behaviour.

But from the next version on (4.2.0.M5) the `_class` property will be defined in the index mapping when the index and its mapping are created by Spring Data Elasticsearch [issue #1711](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/1711).

Comment: Looking forward for the next release

Comment: But is this "_class" field is really needed?

Comment: Let's say you have a class `Entity` with `@Document` and properties. If you only were saving `Entity` instances it would not be needed. But now define a derived class `SubEntity` which might not even add properties but behaviour. You can pass an instance of this subclass to the `ElasticsearchOperations.save(Entity)` method and it will be happily be saved. But when reading it back, you want to have a `SubEntity` and not an `Entity`.  And that's where this information is needed. The same applies to properties which might be declared to have a type but the actual instances can be some subtype.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Type Hints according to Spring documentations. This can be disabled particularly for an object by mentioning

```
@Document(indexName = "index", writeTypeHint = WriteTypeHint.FALSE)
```

This can also be disabled also for all objects by overriding the following method

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfig extends ElasticsearchConfiguration {
    @Override
    public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
        return ClientConfiguration.builder()
        .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
        .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean writeTypeHints() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

hese are mentioned in the spring documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/reference/elasticsearch/object-mapping.html

But, none of the above technique worked for me throwing the exception `Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "_class"`

Rather, I have created a setter method for "_class" and marked it as ReadOnlyProperty. This will only read from elasticstore but will not write any value to elasticstore.

```
@Document(indexName = "ELASTIC_SEARCH_INDEX_NAME")
public class ESDTO implements Serializable {
    @Field
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    @AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)
    public void set_class(String _class) {}
}
```